# PHP and JSON in JQuery

Tags: php, jquery, json

I'm generating a json file with php and store it on my server.
Here is the code for exporting the json

```
/**
 * FUNCTIONS TO EXPORT AS JSON
 */
public function expose() {
    return array(
             'guid' => $this->guid,
               'title' => $this->title,
               'folder' => $this->folder,
               'owner' => $this->owner,
                 #'pictures' => json_encode(array_values($this->pictures), JSON_FORCE_OBJECT),
                 'excude' => $this->excude,
                 'added' => $this->added,
                 'lastViewed' => $this->lastViewed,
        );
    #return get_object_vars($this);
}

public function toJSON(){
    return json_encode($this->expose(), JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
}
```

The content of the file is this:

> {"guid":"","title":"Sample Gallery","folder":"sampleGallery","owner":"","excude":true,"added":"","lastViewed":""}

then in my html file I try to load this with jquery, but I fail to get the objects to the console

```
$.getJSON('/files/galleries/index/sampleGallery.gallery', function(data) {
    console.log(data); // works!
var jsonObj = jQuery.parseJSON(data); 
for (key in jsonObj) {
    console.log(key+':'+JSON.stringify(jsonObj[key]));
}
});
```

Note that the loading of json works fine!

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: you are parsing a javascript object.. no need to parse it since already is a javascript object

Comment: Are you sure that the path to your *sampleGallery.gallery* file is correct in regards to the www server?

Comment: yes, the server returns a correct json file works now with removing the line jQuery.parseJSON(data);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are returning the data as JSON, you don't need to parse it again. JQuery has already done that for you.

```
$.getJSON('/files/galleries/index/sampleGallery.gallery', function(data) {
    console.log(data); // works!
    for (key in data) {
        console.log(key+':'+JSON.stringify(data[key]));
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to call parseJSON(), beacase data is already an object.

Answer (score 0):

I think your data is already parsed because you call getJSON, you should access directly the `data` object and avoid the `jQuery.parseJSON(data);` call.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to do `var jsonObj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);`. [jQuery.getJson](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) parses the returned value as a json object before calling the success callback.

Your code should be

```
$.getJSON('/files/galleries/index/sampleGallery.gallery', function(data) {
    console.log(data); // works!
    for (key in data) {
        console.log(key+':'+JSON.stringify(data[key]));
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Presumably `data` contains parsed JSON (i.e. a JavaScript object).

Trying to parse a JavaScript object as if it were a string containing JSON isn't going to work.

Get rid of `var jsonObj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);` and then `for (var key in data) {`

Answer (score 0):

data is already an object, no need to parse it.

Just read the manual: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do `jQuery.parseJSON(data)` any more, since you are using `getJSON`.

Check out the documentation here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

I think your code should be:

```
$.getJSON('/files/galleries/index/sampleGallery.gallery', function(data) {
    console.log(data); // works!
// jsonObj removed, just use data since data is in JSON already
for (key in data) {
    console.log(key+':'+JSON.stringify(jsonObj[key]));
}
});
```